# Lync for Receptionist

Tags: lync

We want to use Lync Attendant for our front desk but I'm confused on how to set this up.  We usually have one receptionist that's up there, but when she goes to lunch, there can be any number of different people covering the front desk.

I'm wondering if I should set up one account called 'receptionist' and have anyone covering the front desk log into that account.  The drawback of that is that the people can't work on their things when they're up at the front desk.

I can each have them log into the computer front desk computer.  That way, they can work on their own things AND answer calls.  The problem is that they'll have to log into the phone up there too.  That sounds like a pain.

So I wanted to see how anyone else solved this problem.  What are you guys doing for your front desk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lync provides this capability through Response Groups. Have a look at:

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398584.aspx.
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/ilvancri/archive/2010/11/23/creating-a-response-group-in-lync.aspx

The Attendant Client is just an alternate client for Lync.